# Cauchys integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have been tasked with finding $\int_\gamma \frac{Re(z)}{2z-1}$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle. I've tried this a few times and each time I get a different answer, I've ended up with $i\pi/2, -\pi/2 $ and $i\pi/4$. Not sure where I'm going wrong/if I'm even going right! After this, I was told to use the substitution $z=e^{it}$ to solve $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{cos^2t}{5-4sint}dt$ I have performed the substitution and have no idea where to go from there. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use contour integration, note that $2\text{Re}(z)=z+1/z$
on the unit circle. So you get
$$\frac12\int_\gamma\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2z-1}\,dz$$
which involves looking at two simple poles.

Comment: I used this method and ended up $i\pi/2$ and I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: Tried it again, same method, and got $-\pi/4$

Comment: @Deke What residues do you get at $z=0$ and at $z=1/2$?

Comment: I haven't learnt about residues at the moment, so I don't know what they are :(

Comment: @Deke If you want to avoid residues, but the integrand into partial fractions, and use Cauchy's integral formula. But better, **learn** about residues $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: Will try again and see how it goes, thanks alot! any hints for the second part?

Answer (score 0):

A no-brainer substitution approach leads to

$$I=\oint_{\|z\|=1}\frac{\text{Re}(z)}{2z-1}\,dz = i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta}{2e^{i\theta}-1}e^{i\theta}\,d\theta=i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)\,d\theta}{2-e^{-i\theta}}$$
then, by geometric series, to:
$$ I = i\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\theta)e^{-ni\theta}\,d\theta$$
where the orthogonality relations give that only the contribute associated with $n=1$ differs from zero. It follows that
$$ I = \frac{i}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta = \frac{\pi i}{4}.$$
About the second part, you don't really need residues.
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)d\theta}{5-4\sin\theta}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)d\theta}{5+4\sin\theta}=10\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)d\theta}{25-16\sin^2\theta}=20\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)\,d\theta}{9+16\cos^2\theta} $$
and by letting $\theta=\arctan t$ the last integral boils down to:
$$ 20\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{(1+t^2)(25+9t^2)}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
by partial fraction decomposition.